# How to delete all elements that has a vowel in an array [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to eliminate just the vowels from my dynamic array.
with this function i just get blank spaces like this.

[image]

```
char* eliminarVocales(char* arreglo, int*size)
{
    if (arreglo != nullptr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
        {            
            if (arreglo[i] == 'a' || arreglo[i] == 'e' || arreglo[i] == 'i' || arreglo[i] == 'o' || arreglo[i] == 'u')
            {                
                arreglo[i] = NULL;                
            }                
        }
        return arreglo;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are blank spaces because you put them there. `arreglo[i] = NULL;` -- What did you expect to happen with that line of code?  Second, I don't see any "dynamic arrays" in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting blanks because you are not actually removing any characters from your array, you are just replacing them will nulls, and then not ignoring the nulls when outputting the contents of the array.

Instead of doing the removal manually, consider using the standard [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm, which can move any vowels to the end of the array. And since you are passing the array `size` by pointer, you can modify its value to indicate the new size of the array minus any moved vowels.

For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

char* eliminarVocales(char* arreglo, int* size)
{
    if (arreglo)
    {
        *size = std::distance(
            arreglo,
            std::remove_if(arreglo, arreglo + *size,
                [](int ch){ ch = std::toupper(ch); return ((ch == 'A') || (ch == 'E') || (ch == 'I') || (ch == 'O') || (ch == 'U')); }
            )
        );
    }
    return arreglo;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
void listarElementos(char* arreglo, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] : " << arreglo[i] << std::endl;
}

...

#include <cstring>

int size = 5;
char *arreglo = new char[size];
std::strcpyn(arreglo, "hello", 5);
...
listarElementos(arreglo, size); // shows "hello"
... 
eliminarVocales(arreglo, &size);
...
listarElementos(arreglo, size); // shows "hll"
...
delete[] arreglo;
```

If you use a `std::vector` (or `std::string`) for your character array, you can then use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void eliminarVocales(std::vector<char> &arreglo)
{
    arreglo.erase(
        std::remove_if(arreglo.begin(), arreglo.end(),
            [](int ch){ ch = std::toupper(ch); return ((ch == 'A') || (ch == 'E') || (ch == 'I') || (ch == 'O') || (ch == 'U')); }
        ),
        arreglo.end()
    );
}
```

```
void listarElementos(const std::vector<char> &arreglo)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < arreglo.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] : " << arreglo[i] << std::endl;
}

...

#include <cstring>

std::vector<char> arreglo(5);
std::strcpyn(arr.data(), "hello", 5);
...
listarElementos(arreglo); // shows "hello"
... 
eliminarVocales(arreglo);
...
listarElementos(arreglo); // shows "hll"
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply i'm now allowed to use the vector library. I edited your answer, with my listar funcion and my delete an element with index that works. who can i do that for the vowels. ty

Answer (score 1):

Your program is not removing the vowels, but instead it is replacing their values by "NULL". So in the main function where you are calling this function. You have to write another function (e.g., display function) where you have to display only those values where the value!=NULL.

```
for(i=0;i>maxvalue;i++)
{
  if(arreglo[i] != NULL)
    {
    cout<<"[i]"<<arreglo[i]<<endl;         
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helped u.

Comment: This works, but its not eliminating that, i need to eliminate the "box" of the array